# ClassCastException will be thrown when the code attempts to downcast a Tree to a Redwood

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

In below code, at Line 7 when we are downcasting Tree to Redwood there is no error, but why we get a runtime error at line 10 when downcasting Tree to Redwood

```
public class Redwood extends Tree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Redwood().go();
    }
    void go() {
        go2(new Tree(), new Redwood());
        go2((Redwood) new Tree(), new Redwood());// no error here
    }
    void go2(Tree t1, Redwood r1) {
        Redwood r2 = (Redwood)t1;// runtime error here
        Tree t2 = (Tree)r1;
    }
}
class Tree { }
```

Comment: Please format the code. This is not readable.

Comment: Please format the code as code.

Comment: The title is absolutely correct. However, what happens to the code execution when an Exception is thrown? Follow the code execution from the beginning until the Exception is thrown (and then after) to verify the reported output is indeed logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, while a `Redwood` instance is always a `Tree` instance, not all `Tree` instances are a `Redwood`. When you create a `Tree` instance (with `new Tree()`) it is certainly not a `Redwood` instance, and cannot be cast to `Redwood`.

`Redwood r2 = (Redwood)t1;` throws a `ClassCastException` when `t1` is not a `Redwood`. In the first call to `go2`, the first argument is `new Tree()`, which is not a `Redwood`.

Oh, and the reason you see an error here - `Redwood r2 = (Redwood)t1;` (line 10) and not on line 7 (`go2((Redwood) new Tree(), new Redwood());`) is that line 10 is executed first, at the first call to `go2()` (line 6). If you comment line 6, you'll get an exception in line 7.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast an object of type `Tree` into a `Redwood` since it is not that type. You can only cast a variable of parent type into one of the child types if it was actually created as that child type.

This is legal, for example:

```
Tree t = new Redwood();
((Redwood)t).someMethod();
```

But you can't convert an object of parent type, so what you are doing is impossible:

```
Tree t = new Tree();
((Redwood)t).someMethod();
```

The object is not reserved memory based on `Redwood`, nor is it constructed as one, so it cannot suddenly be one.

Since the casting is legal in some cases, the compiler will allow it. At runtime you will run into the problem on line 10 first when calling it from line 6, as debugging line by line would show.

The compiler could be smart enough to tell on compile time that the line 7 will never work, but it wasn't implemented.

Comment: Why does line 7 (as reported by the OP) not throw an exception then?

Comment: You didn't explain that. This answer simply restated the title and verified the reported runtime result in one case, but not the other.

Comment: @user2864740 No, what occurred, not what was expected. But updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

okay here is a simplify version of an explanation that helped me understand the whole thing:
The rule is: this will work:

- Parent p = new Child();
- Child c = new Child();

But this won't work:

- Child c = new Parent();

Answer (score -2):

At line 7 u are just passing the agruments, actual assignment is being done in line 9 which is equivalent to the following code:
Tree T1= (Redwood)new Tree(); // which is fine because base class can hold object of derive class as well as base class. But in line 10 , u r assigning T1 to R2 where T1 actually holds object of base class, which u are trying to assign to Redwood reference forcefully(by casting), java doesn't allow this as if you will call the methods of Redwood class(which are not in Tree) from this R2 reference than it will not be able to call because it actually holds base class object. Hence classcast exception.

Comment: Line 7 is as illegal as line 10, however line 7 is never reached because of the exception thrown during execution of line 6 -> line 10.

Comment: you are right that exception at line 10 is because of the line 6 but even if you comment line 6  line 7 will not cause exception because it is just passing the argument , assignment of these arguments is being done at line 9 , which is where it will cause an exception.

Comment: Have you tried it? If you comment out line 6 I get a ClassCastException at line 7...